# change image of img tag using innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

i want to change image using innerhtml of img tag when i click on it my code is given below

```
tempData +='<td >';

        tempData +='<img src="'+frontImg+'" id='+ii+' onClick="flipImage(this.id);" />';//from where flipImage call
        tempData +='</td>';
```

it works fine but it change image when it return form the function but i wanted to change it before `flipImage` return

```
    function flipImage(m)
    {

        var jsonLen = jsonImages.images.length;
        var imgNumber = finalImageArray[m];
        for(jsn = 0;jsn <jsonLen ;jsn++)
        {
            if(jsonImages.images[jsn].imageKey== imgNumber)
            {
                realImage = jsonImages.images[jsn].imagePath;
                var element = document.getElementById(m);
//              var mg = '<img src="bool.jpg" />'; // change when this line execute what should i put here.?
                //element.innerHTML=mg; want like this.

                       //this is actual code but it change image after returning the function  so i don't want this.
                element.innerHTML=realImage;
            element.setAttribute('src',realImage);
            element.setAttribute('onclick', ''); 
                break;

            }
        }
    }
```

so i wanted to change image before `flipImage` return.
this is just a sample code and

Comment: An `<img>` element has no innerhtml - it's a singleton and will most likely NEVER have child elements, which is what innerhtml is for.

Comment: Reference: *//this is actual code but*. Why not run function to change image, then return back here so `flipImage` function then will continue? Also, does your Question Title reflect img innerHTML for the `tempData` variable... meaning you want the change to occur with that?

Comment: because I want to to flip image but if images are not same then user can see the preview of second image. actually it is a game if two images are not same then user can see the images for a while and then close automatically.so if the images are not same then it not changes the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `innerHTML` for `<img />` tags as they don't have HTML inside them, they're singletons and have no inside contents.

Just use `imgElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://...');` to change the image.